# Inserting data from an XML file into table

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I am trying to get data from an XML file on the web into my datbase so that I can use it.

I have produced the following code, but as its been a long time since I have done coding, imlost with the error message that I am getting.

The error is "Unknown column '10074' in 'field list'".

10074 is the produce ID of the first item in the XML file.

Any pointers would be really useful as it is doing my head in!

The code I have is as follows:

```
    <?php
   $Products = simplexml_load_file('http://atsdistribution.co.uk/feeds/xml_all_products.aspx');


$con = mysql_connect(Details);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("catflaps_products", $con);


foreach($Products->Product as $Product)
{
$ProductID = $Product->ProductID;
$Name = $Product->Name;
$DropshipPrice = $Product->DropshipPrice;
$SRP = $Product->SRP;
$Brand = $Product->Brand;
$Xline = $Product->Xline;
$InStock = $Product->InStock;
$Stock = $Product->Stock;
$Barcode = $Product->Barcode;
$Weight = $Product->Weight;
$CategoryID = $Product->CategoryID;
$Category = $Product->Category;
$SmallImage = $Product->SmallImage;
$LargeImage = $Product->LargeImage;
$Description = $Product->Description;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(ProductID, Name, DropshipPrice, SRP, Brand, Xline, InStock, Stock, Barcode, Weight, CategoryID, Category, SmallImage, LargeImage, Description)
VALUES(`$ProductID`, `$Name` , `$DropshipPrice`, `$SRP`, `$Brand`, `$Xline`, `$InStock`, `$Stock`, `$Barcode`, `$Weight`, `$CategoryID`, `$Category`, `$SmallImage`, `$LargeImage`, `$Description`)")
        or die(mysql_error());

}

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not use backquotes inside VALUES part. It's only to quote mysql identifiers (like table, column names). I think if you remove it your problem will be solved
2. You should use quotes (regular ones either ' or ") when you quote string value in VALUES part (but see below, there is a better approach)
3. If you choose #2, then you need to properly escape your values from XML by using mysql_real_escape_string in your case. In fact, this is a breach in security (see SQL injections) if you don't do this. But even if you say this is a temporary script one-time usage etc, you'll probably end up with another error when there is single- or double-quote in your xml data
4. The best approach is using PDO prepare statements, then you don't bother quoting certain datatypes with quotes or not doing this - you bind certain param with its datatype. And remember that mysql_* functions are deprecated today.

So this code works like a charm:

```
<?php
$Products = simplexml_load_file('xml_all_products.xml');
$config = array('db' => array(
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'host'   => 'localhost:4040',
    'username' => 'xx',
    'password' => 'xxx'
));
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'].';host='.$config['db']['host'],$config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password']);

foreach($Products->Product as $Product)
{
    $ProductID = $Product->ProductID;
    $Name = $Product->Name;
    $DropshipPrice = $Product->DropshipPrice;
    $SRP = $Product->SRP;
    $Brand = $Product->Brand;
    $Xline = $Product->Xline;
    $InStock = $Product->InStock;
    $Stock = $Product->Stock;
    $Barcode = $Product->Barcode;
    $Weight = $Product->Weight;
    $CategoryID = $Product->CategoryID;
    $Category = $Product->Category;
    $SmallImage = $Product->SmallImage;
    $LargeImage = $Product->LargeImage;
    $Description = $Product->Description;

    $ProductsRS = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test(ProductID, Name, DropshipPrice, SRP, Brand, Xline, InStock, Stock, Barcode, Weight, CategoryID, Category, SmallImage, LargeImage, Description)
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $ProductsRS->execute(array($ProductID, $Name, $DropshipPrice, $SRP, $Brand, $Xline, $InStock, $Stock, $Barcode, $Weight, $CategoryID, $Category, $SmallImage, $LargeImage, $Description));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That realyly does work like a charm!

I have been out of the game for far too long! CHeers!